# ubuntu 20.04 wicd setup

Tags: wicd

I'm using ubuntu server 20.04.
How do I setup wicd?
How do I connect wicd with netplan?

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb -y
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb -y
```

Comment: From the looks of it that is a python 2 version so I would advice to drop this idea.  20.04 does not have python 2. There is no python 3 version of wicd for Ubuntu; 1.7.4 seems to be the last one.

Comment: My goal is to install a light weight network manager gui to set a static ip... Is that possible ubuntu 20.04 server